# How to send a String through java application to a focused field background application; excel for example?

Tags: java

I want to send a string data through desktop java application to a focused field everywhere on a computer like IPWEDGE for zebra devices.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You could copy to the system clipboard.

Comment: I'm just starting to code